# How to gain access to Salesforce Commerce Cloud sandbox

Tags: commerce-cloud

I want to build a Demandware cartridge. I have partnered with Saleforce and oaid the trial fee of $2500. Now I want to start development.

I believe I need access to the sandbox. How do I get this? The documentation says "Get a sandbox from Commerce Cloud Support if you are a customer or partner developer. If you are a link partner developer, get a sandbox from your link partner program manager". So I need to contact Salesforce? I tried this and got no response. Is there no automatic way of accessing the sandbox?

Comment: do you have to pay 2500 to get a sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to contact Commerce Cloud Support or your link partner program manager.

There is no automated way to do this because Commerce Cloud is not built on Salesforce Core. It is not multi-tenant. You have to go through Salesforce support.